# Custom Navigation Bar in ios6 and ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a problem to which I can't found a solution right now. In my application I have multiple buttons in my NavigationBar which are required throughout the app, rather than creating the buttons in every view controller I want to make a sub class of UINavigationBar or UINavigationController(i don't know which one). So that whenever the user moves between the views the navigation bar always contains those buttons. I have searched very much till now regarding this but couldn't found anything worth.
Please suggest me a way to do so, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "CustomNavBar.h"

@implementation CustomNavBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.tintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Custom-Nav-Bar-BG.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, self.frame.size.height)];

    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [btn drawRect:CGRectMake(42, 0, 40, self.frame.size.height )];

    UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [btn2 drawRect:CGRectMake(82, 0, 40, self.frame.size.height )];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subClass standard `UINavigationBar` to achieve this

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(<#selector#>) forControlEvents:<#(UIControlEvents)#>]
        [self addSubview:btn];

        ...
        ...


    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);
}

@end
```

To use this is `StoryBoard` or `xib`, simply change standard class name to `CustomNavigationBar`.

**OR**

If you want it programmatically

In `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];

    UIStoryboard *mStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    ViewController *VC1 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];


    [navVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:VC1] animated:NO];
    [self. window setRootViewController:navVC];

    [self. window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```